# How to make a chocolate fudge/syrup sauce that does not freeze?

Tags: sauce, freezing, chocolate, syrup

I'm looking for a good recipe to make a chocolate fudge/syrup style sauce that will not freeze solid when placed in the freezer, but rather retain its "liquid" consistency.  It does not need to be runny when frozen, but I just do not want it to freeze.

I plan to add it into an ice cream cake so do not want it to solidify or become hard when I bite into the cake.

Any suggestions for something that would work well?

**EDIT**

I tried something with chocolate, evaporated milk and butter and sugar, and although functional (ie: does not seem to freeze solid, but becomes taffy like), tastes way too buttery  for me.

My recipe was something along the lines of:

```
1/2 cup butter
3 oz chocolate
2 cup sugar
350ml evaporated milk
```

Basically melt butter & chocolate, add sugar and milk and reduce to desired consistency.  But like I said, although it works, it is way too buttery.

I would love to figure out a recipe that would allow me to do make something of a similar consistency, but with dairy free w/ dark chocolate (ie: no milk/butter).  But I am not sure what gives the sauce the taffy consistency vs. freezing up.  I immediately discounted any recipes that I saw which were water based due to the freezing/crystalizing issue.

**END EDIT**

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: Is there a particular recipe you're looking at modifying? Or are you asking how to determine (from looking at a recipe) if it'll get hard in the freezer? More details will definitely help.

Comment: I don't have a particular recipe that I am using.  Years ago I had come up with a good combination of ingredients that gave me the perfect consistency, but have long since lost it.  And with the proliferation of recipes for chocolate sauce that I can easily find, I can't seem to find any that are classified as "freezer-friendly".  And quite frankly, I have no idea how to determine by looking at their ingredients if they are freezable without hardening.  So either a complete recipe, or helpful tips to ensure that a recipe would not freeze, would be appreciated.

Comment: The freezing/melting point for many syrups is lower than 0 C I think. I would think that most chocolate syrups would stay liquid for a bit below freezing. Have you tried making a syrup that didn't stay liquid? I'd maybe start there. Post up a recipe for eat you've done, and we can give you a better answer.

Comment: Edited to add a recipe that works but am not happy with.

Answer (score 5):

Alcohol Sugar Fat. Your recipe needs to be more of those and less of water; just like an ice cream.

I had luck with agave syrup as a base (maple or cornsyrup?) that I tested by freezing; when I was satisfied by my choice, I melted in chocolate and additional fat (good coconut oil I think).

Certainly won't be fudgy outside of freezer so finding a recipe is tricky...

Have a look also at that ice cream topping chocolate hard-shell. It has a super low melting point with its high fat content. Wouldn't take much more sugar in the form of a syrup to make it fudgy.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Wished I had seen your msg before trying something out last night.  Is kind of along the lines of the same thing, just that i used butter as a fat and evaporated milk as a liquid, and although good, tastes way too buttery for me.  Will have to try with coconut oil next time instead.

Answer (score 3):

First, one obvious thought is to use a fat that doesn't solidify, like most vegetable oils. Hazelnut oil is really delicious in chocolate sauce and will probably have the right effect. If you don't want that flavour you could try groundnut or almond oil. I guess you might need some emulsifier though to prevent it separating. A little corn flour might do it (it's great in Spanish hot chocolate, so why not?).

Second, glucose (powder or syrup, it doesn't matter) leads to a lower freezing point than normal sugar (sucrose). That is at least partly because, since it is much less sweet than sucrose, you need to use more for the same sweetness, leading to higher content of sugars which will lower the freezing point. I use a mix of glucose and sucrose to make soft-scoop ice cream at home.

Comment: When you say glucose, would corn syrup work the same?  I know they aren't exactly the same, but I'm thinking they are similar enough.

Answer (score 1):

I know adding marshmallows will make it taffy-like melting the chocolate and adding the marshmallows and stir quickly to dissolve it like making fudge
Have you considered reducing the amount of butter in it?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a basic ganache  receipe but it isn't dairy free.